# Find the max and min values in a python dictionary, with requirement that they belong to distinct keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I am iterating through a list of lists and recording the max and min value of each list.
I have the following code which stores the max value and min value of a list using the index of the array as the key.

```python
def maxAndMin( arrays):
        i=0
        d= {}
        for a in arrays:
            maxNum = max(a)
            minNum = min(a)
            d[i] = [minNum, maxNum]
            i+=1 
        print d
```

I want to find the largest value in the dictionary and also the smallest value with the requirement that they are mapped to from different keys (not found in the same array). Cannot find a working solution yet.

Edit: Input: [[1, 3, 4], [0, 2, 5]]. Want to return max=5, min=1 or max=4, min=0. Not max=5, min=0, since 5 and 0 are in the same list.

Edit2: Find the max in the values first, then find the minimum and require that the minimum not have the same key as the max.

Comment: post the input list and expected result

Comment: What output do you want if the largest and smallest values *do* correspond to the same key?

Comment: @user2357112 I want get the max first, then get the minimum and require that the minimum not have the same key as the max.

Answer (score 1):

So you *say* you are working with a dictionary, but your sample input is actually a list of lists. Translating your requirements in the most straightforward way, we can achieve this in two passes:

> Find the max in the values first, then find the minimum and require
>   that the minimum not have the same key as the max.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> l = [[1, 3, 4], [0, 2, 5]]
>>> flattened = ((i, e) for i, sub in enumerate(l) for e in sub)
>>> max_idx, maxval = max(flattened, key=itemgetter(1))
>>> minval = min(e for i, sub in enumerate(l) if i != max_idx for e in sub)
>>> print("Max:", maxval, "Min:", minval)
Max: 5 Min: 1
```

The above is essentially equivalent to the following:

```
>>> l = [[1, 3, 4], [0, 2, 5]]
>>> maxval = float('-inf')
>>> max_idx = 0
>>> for i, sub in enumerate(l):
...     for e in sub:
...         if e > maxval:
...             maxval = e
...             max_idx = i
...
>>> minval = float('inf')
>>> for i, sub in enumerate(l):
...     if i != max_idx:
...         for e in sub:
...             if e < minval:
...                 minval = e
...
>>> print("Max:", maxval, "Min:", minval)
Max: 5 Min: 1
```